# Why is it possible to divide 0 by 0D but not by 0?

Tags: c#, integer, double, divide-by-zero

I was wondering why

```
0D / 0D
```

outputs `NaN` (*Not a Number*), but

```
0 / 0
```

*can't even compile* due to `DivideByZeroException`

Comment: `0/0` is dividing two `int`s, not `double`s; `int` doesn't have any `NaN` value

Comment: Minor issue with your question, but an 'exception' doesn't happen at compile time, they are run-time only.

Comment: The compiler doesn't throw a `DivideByZeroException` (exceptions happen at runtime). What you see is a compiler error like `Compilation error (line 8, col 11): Division by constant zero`.

Answer (score 4):

Well,

```
0 / 0
```

is dividing `int` by `int` and thus the outcome should be `int`; 
since `int` doesn't have any *special value* like `+INF`, `-INF`, `NaN` throwing exception (`DivideByZeroException`) 
is the only option. `0 / 0` is divinding two *constants* which can be performed at *compile time*.

On the contrary, in case of

```
0d / 0d
```

the outcome should be of type `double` where *special value* can well be returned:

```
 1d / 0d = +INF (positive infinity)
-1d / 0d = -INF (negative infinity)
 0d / 0d =  NAN (math uncertainty; technically, result can be +/-INF or some finite number)
```

In the last case we have *uncertainty*; the result is *undefined* and we are given `NAN`.

Comment: NaN doesn't mean it can be "Infinity or a finite number". NaN means the result is just undefined.

Comment: @Adrian: Thank you, I should have elaborated the last case.